# Magento 2.4.6: How to add virtual product to cart when adding simple product to cart using graphql mutation?

Tags: addtocart, magento2.4.6, magento-graphql

I'm trying to add virtual product to cart when we add simple product to cart using Graphql mutation.

How I can pass the virtual product data with the simple product data?

Can someone help me on this?

Thank you.